# Spinner shows empty when use fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, spinner

I have a spinner in normal activity and a wants to try to use spinner in fragment but in the fragment, shows empty when run it
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kX9Ex.png)

My code in *onCreateView*

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View vista =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pag1,container,false);



    calcular= (Button)vista.findViewById(R.id.button);
    etd=(EditText)vista.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    resultadocp=(TextView)vista.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    lista = (Spinner)vista.findViewById(R.id.spinner);

String []opciones={"one","two","three","four","five"};

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, opciones);
lista.setAdapter(adapter);    return vista;  }
```

Comment: define your dropdown resource before assigning adapter by using setDropDownViewResource

Comment: Can you post the fragment_pag1.xml?

Comment: fragment http://pastebin.com/b0j08Pnn (stackoverflow Don´t let me put the ALL code here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example one:**

You can use this

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, opciones);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
lista.setAdapter(adapter);
```

`Insted of

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, opciones);
lista.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**Example two:**

Create spinner xml

```
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/spinner"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Add your spinner string to string.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string-array name="string_array">
    <item>one</item>
    <item>two</item>
    <item>three</item>
    <item>four</item>
    <item>five</item>
</string-array>
```

Add this code to your fragment

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner)lista.findViewById(R.id.spinner);

ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this.getActivity(),
    R.array.string_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

 adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

just try this...
I hope it works for you...

Comment: plz post your spinner xml....I think your spinner empty because of this spinner xml.

Comment: The same error, you can try my project and watch it https://mega.nz/#!sVoBQTKK!pnkOgUroDlhR41wuVsG8Nqu0qyFg9o7YVWSLbp5ARoo

Comment: I fix it, if you use populate spinner, you put this line in the xml of spinner,                                                    android:entries="@array/string_array"

Comment: I found error on your spinner please change lista = (Spinner)vista.findViewById(R.id.spinner1); Instead of Spinner spinner = (Spinner)lista.findViewById(R.id.spinner); Because your spinner Id is spinner1 and you are passing only spinner

Comment: you are doing right on your coding but you forget to change spinner1 Instead of spinner Id

Answer (score 0):

Easy if only title is missing and dropdown working

```
spinner.setPrompt("Title"); or xml: android:prompt="@string/title"
```

Btw can you elaborate problem and xml file use

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

and override

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // On selecting a spinner item
    String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

    // Showing selected spinner item
}
```

Comment: But its no only the title, when hit the spinner, does nothing

Comment: use this:                                            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);